# How to execute query using script in MySQL Docker image?

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I am trying to give user a `web` interface in which , user can write a `query` and then i will be executing that `query` on my `server`.

I am using the following `MySQL` `docker` image with the `latest tag` i.e. `mysql:latest`

```
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/
```

So i am runnig the docker image using this command

```
 docker run -it --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -v /root/ServerCode/:/usercode  mysql /bin/bash
```

My `root/ServerCode` directory contains a `script` which i want to use for running `mysql` server and user's `query`.

My `script` is

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

It gives me `error`

```
bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried using this

```
service mysqld start
```

It is also giving `error`

```
mysqld: unrecognized service
```

Edit:

```
 #!/bin/bash
set -e  
exec  1> $"/usercode/logfile.txt"
exec  2> $"/usercode/errors"
# These output and error files are in mounted folder which i check after running script
/etc/init.d/mysqld start // run sql server here 
#here i want to run that query and then get out of conatiner `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entyrypoint scipt only does the initdb if **mysqld** is the argument; in your case it sees ***bash*** and so skips the initdb and just runs bash with its arguments.

If you are just trying to run some setup scripts once mysql is running have you looked at ***/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/***?

Create a docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:

    db:
      image: mysql
      container_name: mysql
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - /var/db/startuphry/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        - ./conf/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/settings.cnf
        - ./conf/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      ports:
        - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
```

Create a ***conf*** folder add the ***my.cnf*** file to it

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
```

Create folder ***docker-entrypoint-initdb.d*** inside ***conf*** folder and all sql files inside this folder

Tree looks likes this

```
|____docker-compose.yml
|____conf
      |___my.cnf
      |___docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
                       |___one.sql
                       |___two.sql
```

You can put any ***.sh*** files or .sql files in there and they will be run/imported before the mysql service is available outside the container.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question, I am asking how can i start that "mysqld" service by my own using script

Comment: I would like to share my script with you, so that you can have some idea 
`#!/bin/bash  
set -e  
exec  1> $"/usercode/logfile.txt"  
exec  2> $"/usercode/errors"  
/etc/init.d/mysqld start  
# These output and error files are in mounted folder which i check after running script  
#here i want to run that query and then get out of conatiner `

Comment: I Have added my whole script in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the "/etc/init.d/mysqld start" inside the mysql docker container.
/root/server is a host machine path . Mysql has been installed in container not in the host machine. Please run the "/etc/init.d/mysqld start " not in the host machine.

Comment: but the command "/etc/init.d/mysqld start " is in script file which is mounted in docker using " -v /root/ServerCode/:/usercode ", so it will be running that command in docker itself. Please correct me if i am wrong.